# how to convert PHP GD generated images into PDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation

our website has a certification image created by PHP GD, and I can print and watch it on a web page. But I couldn't make it a downloadable PDF file. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: What you want is to **embed** it into a PDF, not converting it into one.

Answer (score 2):

You can first save the image somewhere and then use the [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) lib to write it in a PDF file

Answer (score 2):

you could use imagick to do this..
the below command does the trick if your server is properly configured - Imagick is installed, GhostScript is installed, php is allowed to execute shell commands, etc

```
 shell_exec('convert /path/to/input.png /path/to/output.pdf')
```